# Adobe Illustrator Extendscript - Printing to specific printer with custom page size

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

In Adobe Illustrator, I'm making a script to automate putting a label on a document and then sending it to the correct printer without any user interaction.

The document successfully makes it to the printer, custom page size part is being ignored.

I just want simulate the equivalent of changing the page size to 'Custom' manually in the Illustrator print dialog box (which correctly sets the dimensions of what gets sent to the printer)

```
 // get dimensions for custom paper size
 var docRef = app.activeDocument;
 var boardWidth = docRef.width;
 var boardHeight = docRef.height;

 var paperOpts = new PrintPaperOptions;
 var printOpts = new PrintOptions;
 printOpts.paperOptions = paperOpts;

 // custom page size (gets ignored)
 paperOpts.name = 'Custom';
 paperOpts.width = boardWidth + 0.0;
 paperOpts.height = boardHeight + 0.0;

 printOpts.printerName = 'HP_Designjet_L26500_Onyx_PosterShop';        
 printOpts.PPDName = 'HP Designjet L26500 Onyx PosterShop'; 

 docRef.print(printOpts);
```

Expected results - the same as manually going to File | Print, selecting the printer and selecting page size: Custom, and hitting print.

Actual results: Most of what is sent to the printer is cropped out, or there's whitespace around the edge, the page size is incorrect.